# Proof involving polynomial roots

Tags: polynomials, roots

From USAMO 1977:
"If $a$ and $b$ are two roots of $x^4+x^3-1=0$, prove that $ab$ is a root of $x^6+x^4+x^3-x^2-1=0$."

The solutions I've seen for this problem all involve manipulating Vieta's equations relating polynomial roots and coefficients. In particular, the solutions feel a bit like they've been plucked out of thin air, in that I don't understand their motivation. So I'd be interested to see some alternate solutions/extra explanation.

I instead tried to construct $(ab)^6+(ab)^4+(ab)^3-(ab)^2-1=0$ using $a^4+a^3-1=0$ and $b^4+b^3-1=0$, but was unsuccessful.

Comment: You can see here https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=1977_USAMO_Problems/Problem_3

Comment: By using your approach, how do you use the fact that $a\not=b$?

Comment: thanks, but I have already looked at that solution, and didn't really understand the motivation

Comment: @RobertZ I subtracted the two equations from each other and factored out the $a-b$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering

\begin{align}
  x^4+x^3-1 &= (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d) \\
  S_1 &= a+b+c+d \\
  &= -1 \\
  S_2 &= ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd \\
  &= 0 \\
  S_3 &= bcd+acd+abd+abc \\
  &= 0 \\
  S_4 &= abcd \\
  &= -1 \end{align}

> The sextic has a nice symmetry so that all the roots are $ab$, $ac$, $ad$, $bc$, $bd$ and $cd$.

Now, using **`SymmetricReduction[(x-a b)(x-a c)(x-a d)(x-b c)(x-b d)(x-c d),{a,b,c,d}]`** in *Wolfram Alpha* or so, we have:

\begin{align}
  f(x) &= (x-\color{red}{ab})(x-\color{red}{ac})(x-\color{red}{ad})
  (x-\color{red}{bc})(x-\color{red}{bd})(x-\color{red}{cd}) \\
  &= x^6-S_2 x^{5}+(S_1 S_3-S_4)x^{4}+(2S_2 S_4-S_3^2-S_1^2 S_4)x^{3} \\
  & \quad +(S_1 S_3 S_4-S_4^2)x^{2}-S_2 S_4^2 x+S_4^3 \\
  &= x^6+x^4+x^3-x^2-1
\end{align}

Comment: +1 Beautiful insight.

Comment: Can you explain why 
"The sextic has a nice symmetry so that all the roots are ab, ac, ad, bc, bd and cd" is true?

Comment: Since $a$ and $b$ are not specified for which are which, all $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ have equal footings.  That's to say any two of them will do.  Hence there're $\binom{4}{2}=6$ combinations.

Comment: I see, so you're working backwards, thanks

Answer (score 4):

> I instead tried to construct $(ab)^6+(ab)^4+(ab)^3-(ab)^2-1=0$ using $\,\ldots$

Following up on OP's approach, let $\,ab=p\,$ and, for symmetry, $\,a+b=s\,$. To begin with:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
a^4 + a^3 - 1 &= 0 \\
b^4 + b^3 - 1 &= 0
\end{align}
\end{cases} \tag{1}
$$

Subtracting the two equations in $\,(1)\,$, and using that $\,a \ne b\,$:

$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
a^4-b^4+a^3-b^3 = 0 \;\;&\implies\;\; \cancel{(a-b)}(a+b)(a^2+b^2) + \cancel{(a-b)}(a^2+ab+b^2) = 0 \\
 &\implies\;\; s(s^2-2p) + s^2 - p = 0 \\
 &\implies\;\; s^3 + s^2 - (2s+1)p = 0 \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

Adding the two equations in $\,(1)\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
a^4+b^4+a^3+b^3 - 2 = 0 \;\;&\implies\;\; \big((a+b)^4 - 4ab(a^2+b^2)-6a^2b^2\big) \\
 &\quad\quad\quad\quad+\big((a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)\big)-2=0 \\
 &\implies\;\; s^4 - 4p(s^2-2p)-6p^2+s^3-3ps-2 = 0 \\
 &\implies\;\; s^4 + s^3 -4ps^2-3ps+2p^2-2=0 \tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

At this point, the equation satisfied by $\,p\,$ can be derived by eliminating $\,s\,$ between $\,(2)\,$ and $\,(3)\,$. This is usually better left to a CAS since the calculations can be tedious, and e.g. WA gives [resultant[$s^3 + s^2 - (2s+1)p$, $s^4 + s^3 - 4ps^2 - 3ps + 2p^2 - 2, s$] = $8  (p^6 + p^4 + p^3 - p^2 - 1)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%5B%20s%5E3%20%2B%20s%5E2%20-%20(2s%2B1)p,%20s%5E4%20%2B%20s%5E3%20-4ps%5E2-3ps%2B2p%5E2-2,%20s%20%5D).

It can still be done by hand, though. Substituting $\,s^4+s^3=s \cdot (2s+1)p\,$ from $\,(2)\,$ into $\,(3)\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
s(2s+1)p  -4ps^2-3ps+2p^2-2=0 \;\;&\implies\;\; -2ps^2 - 2ps+ 2p^2 - 2 = 0 \\
 &\implies\;\; ps^2+ps-p^2+1 = 0 \tag{4}
\end{align}
$$

Eliminating once again $\,s(s+1)\,$ between $\,(2)\,$ and $\,(4)\,$ by $\,s \cdot (4) - p \cdot (2)\,$ gives:

$$
\begin{align}
0 &= s \cdot \big(\cancel{ps(s+1)}-p^2+1\big) - p \cdot \big(\cancel{s^2(s+1)} - (2s+1)p\big) = (p^2+1)s+p^2 \tag{5}
\end{align}
$$

Then, substituting $\,s = \frac{-p^2}{p^2+1}\,$ back in $\,(4)\,$ gives in the end the sextic $\,p^6 + p^4 + p^3 - p^2 - 1 = 0\,$.

Comment: If we want to use resultants, then directly taking resultant $[a^4+a^3-1, p^4+p^3a-a^4,a]$ does the same job, of course it will include the case $a=p/a=b$ as an additional factor.

Comment: Right, but the calculation is more laborious. That [resultant](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%28a%5E4%2Ba%5E3%E2%88%921%2C+p%5E4%2Bp%5E3a%E2%88%92a%5E4%2C+a%29) is a polynomial of degree $16$, which then needs to be factored, and one of the factors (a [quartic](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%28a%5E4%2Ba%5E3-1%2C+a%5E2-b%2C+a%29)) be identified as corresponding to the extraneous root.

Comment: That's true, though once you go the CAS route, the difference may not matter so much. Besides, we are given a key factor already in the Q.  The hand calculations in the last para clearly is better done following your approach. +1

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is wrong as written, because if $a=b$, then $ab=a^2$ has minimal polynomial $x^{4} - x^{3} - 2 x^{2} + 1$, which doesn't divide $x^6+x^4+x^3-x^2-1$ (the reminder is $7 x^{3} + 6 x^{2} - x - 5$).

I guess that it was meant that $a\neq b$. Then, one may apply Galois theory to get a more straightforward way to compute the minimal polynomial of $ab$ and then to check whether or not it divides $x^6+x^4+x^3-x^2-1$ (it is a root iff the minimal polynomial divides...)

Here is a sketch how to do so: You prove that $\mathbb{Q}(a,b)$ has degree $12$ and a basis $\{a^{i}b^{j}\}$ with $i=0,1,2,3$ and $j=0,1,2$. Then you write a matrix AB for multiplication by $ab$ in this basis (usually it is easier to write a matrix $A$ for $a$, a matrix $B$ for $b$, and to multiply them). The minimal polynomial polynomial will be that of the matrix $AB$.

The downside is that one needs to work with $12\times 12$ matrices. But it is not too bad, since those matrices are essentially block-matrices.