# Cubic formula confusion/clarification

Tags: polynomials, cubics

So the cubic formula yields ultimately a degree 6 equation which is easily solved as it just involves solving a quadratic in $z^3$ but this gives 6 solutions. My question is at what step in the process can we say that 3 of the solutions are equal to each other (as in 6 solutions boils down to 3)?

Comment: Which cubic formula?

Comment: Cardano's formula.

Answer (score 0):

For a reduced cubic $$y^3=3py+2q$$

the **resolvents are symmetric in roles**:

$$u^3+v^3=2q$$

$$uv=p$$

they are **conjugate** to each other,

$$u=\sqrt[3]{q\pm \sqrt{q^{2}-p^{3}}} \implies
v=\frac{p}{\sqrt[3]{q\pm \sqrt{q^{2}-p^{3}}}}
 =\sqrt[3]{q\mp \sqrt{q^{2}-p^{3}}}$$

One of the roots $y=u+v$ is just a matter of **writing order**.

Also one list of roots namely

$$y=u\omega_{3}^{k}+v\omega_{3}^{2k}$$

is equivalent to

$$y=u\omega_{3}^{2k}+v\omega_{3}^{k}$$

where $\omega_n=e^{2\pi i/n}$.

There're **cyclic properties** for polynomial equations.  The **Galois theory** is a group theory about polynomial zeros.  For your interests, see also other posts of mine [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616213/how-to-find-the-complex-roots-of-y3-frac13y-frac2527/1617160#1617160), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2072773/how-to-show-y2-z2-u2-are-roots-of-1?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1654541/principal-roots-in-the-derivation-of-the-quadratic-formula/1654766#1654766) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2857380/proof-involving-polynomial-roots/2857724#2857724).